What does the "?" do in accessing an element in C#?
I usually use ? to assign an variable and check null later.
But this does not work in the following context:
var value = PlayerGroup?.Players?[0]?.jsonData?.playerSetting?.useChat?.value ?? true;

Expected: value == true if PlayerGroup.Players is null or has no elements in array.
Result: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
What the ? do expectly in this context?

As you mentioned, this is null chaining. Checking emptiness of a collection is a completely different matter.

Personally, I think if you're having to use that many question marks you're making your code "overly nullable".. Writing code where anything at any time might be null and needs checking for is wearisome; turn on #nullable, declare as few things as possible as "may be null", start giving sensible defaults to things and don't set things to null willingly where you can help it

The other thing you should do is follow C# naming convention and where you have to work with data from json, use the proper attributes to tell C# what the name of the json property is, rather than naming your c# members in json convention. This means you can have any c# name you like and it still forms the right json. Look at e.g. [JsonProperty("playerSetting")] public BlahBlah Settings {get;set;} (Newtonsoft; STJ is JsonPropertyName)

Players?[0]?
This does not work in the case that Players is not null, but empty, as you have already seemed to figure out. Players[0] will be out of bounds then. Try using FirstOrDefault if that is what you want to do. (?.FirstOrDefault()?.)
